# Rails functional tests- nesting assertion within assert_raises?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tdd

I've got a functional test like the following:

```
test "vendors can't create notes for products they don't own" do
  login vendor
  params = { format: 'json', note: { content: "shouldn't exist" }, vendor_id: other_product.vendor.id }

  assert_raises(CanCan::AccessDenied) do
    assert_no_difference "Note.count" do
      post :create, params
    end
  end
end
```

When run, this test passes, but the output shows only 1 assertion:

```
1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Does these nested `assert_no_difference` assertion even get run, since the `AccessDenied` exception was raised?

If I run them as two separate assertions, like this:

```
assert_raises(CanCan::AccessDenied) do
  post :create, params
end

assert_no_difference "Note.count" do
  post :create, params
end
```

... the test errors out with `CanCan::AccessDenied: You are not authorized to access this page.`  So, does the nested assertion in the first example actually get run?  I know it's somewhat redundant, but it's only a couple of extra lines of code and offers some additional peace of mind (but only if it's actually doing anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your `assert_no_difference` assertion is not run, as you noticed. Raising an exception breaks out of the block completely.

The solution is to reverse the nesting order of your assertions, like so:

```
assert_no_difference "Note.count" do
  assert_raises(CanCan::AccessDenied) do
    post :create, params
  end
end
```

The `assert_raises` call catches the exception, allowing execution to continue, so the outer block completes and the `Note.count` check is performed.